# Multilingual with multiple app and 1 translationService

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I'm currently make a html page by using angularjs.

I have 1 html page, with 1 sidebar, 1 navigation bar and 1 content area.
Like this : [AdminLTE](https://almsaeedstudio.com/preview)

I've follow this instruction : [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/multilingual-support-for-angularjs/)

And successfully, my app works ok. 
But I don't know how to apply multilingual function to my every app.
For example : Navigationbar is 1 app, sidebar is 1 app and main content is 1 app.

How can I apply 1 translationService to 'em without downloading json again and again ?

Can anyone help me please ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using iframes? If so, I don't think it is possible. Or at least it is very difficult to share information between frames.

Comment: Please look the AdminLTE I posted. No iframes here, just divs and divs

Comment: I looked at the link and I see a lot of iframes.

Comment: Oh I see - there are iframes but all of your angular code will be in the inner iframe.

Comment: Why are you using multiple apps, then? I think it would make more sense to have 1 app for everything and have separate controllers for sidebar, nav bar, and content.

Comment: I'm using ASP.Net for making my web application. 
Inside my project, there are some partial views : _Navbar.cshtml, _Sidebar.cshtml, _MainContent.cshtml. And I want 'em to work separately :)

Answer (score 0):

I still think it would be better to have one application for the whole page, but have separate controllers for the nav, sidebar, and main content. That way they all work separately, but you don't have the awkwardness of dealing with separate apps. The only reason I can think of to have separate apps is if you want to make sure that services are NEVER shared between the different parts. However, in your case, it looks like you WANT to share the translate service, so I think it makes sense to use one app.

If you really want to have multiple apps, it is still possible. You can load the translations asynchronously, then when this is done, you call `angular.module()`  for each app and inject the translations as a constant. Then, when you configure the translate provider, you can inject your translation constant just like you would inject any service.

I have done this in an application before, but I don't have access to the code right now. I did it for a single application, but you can easily extend it to multiple applications. I believe it looked similar to this:

```
var $http = angular.injector().get('$http');
var $q = angular.injector().get('$q');
var promises = [
    $http.get('path/to/translations/en.json'),
    $http.get('path/to/translations/fr.json'),
];
$q.all(promises)
   .then(function(translations) {
        angular.module('app', [])
            .constant('translations_en', translations[0])
            .constant('translations_fr', translations[1])
            .config(['$translateProvider', 'translations_en', 'translations_fr', 
                function($translateProvider, translations_en, translations_fr) {
                    $translateProvider.translations('en', translations_en);
                    $translateProvider.translations('fr', translations_fr);
                }]);
        angular.bootstrap(element, ['app']);
    });
```

For multiple apps, you would need to run the `angular.module` block once for each app.

Alternatively, you could define separate modules for each part, then define a parent module that depends on the other mini-modules, i.e.

```
angular.module('navigation', []);
angular.module('sidebar', []);
angular.module('mainPage', []);
angular.module('app', ['navigation', 'sidebar', 'mainPage']);
angular.bootstrap(element, ['app']);
```

I believe that all modules would share the same translate service in this case.